# ASP.NET - Ajax Control Toolkit - TabContainer always hidden

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I used the following code to add TabContainer to page

```
      <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">

        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="tab one" ID="TabPanel0">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

         <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="tab two" ID="TabPanel1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

    </asp:TabContainer>
```

but when the page is rendered TabPanel is always Hidden,I wateched the html code by Firebug and found visibility is hidden... what is the problem? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1eSW.jpg

Comment: You did anything in the code behind or javascript, because it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to set the ActiveTab-Property(from codebehind) or the ActiveTabIndex from codebehind or aspx?

You could also check if it works if you explicitly set the display to visible:

```
ActiveTabIndex="0" style="display:block;visibility:visible;"
```

Are you sure that the Ajax libraries are loaded correctly? Do you have other Ajax-Controls inside of your TabContainer? Check if all of your html in that page is valid.

Are you using the latest AjaxToolkit and the ToolkitScriptManager instead of the ScriptManger?

Comment: I used ScriptMangager instead of ToolkitScriptManager because of a problem and tips on this page http://forums.asp.net/t/1273185.aspx/2/10 ,it is the problem of .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Script Manager from the Ajax Control Toolkit, add it after the form tag.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue and after 2 hours of googling i found a solution. In my case I had to change asp:ScriptManager to ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager.

Answer (score 0):

You may want check that you have used `ToolkitScriptManager` instead of `ScriptManager`. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

We've solved this problem at our company, after trying everything found on websites by changing the website's appPool from Classic to Integrated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: The active tab was hidden (server side: `Visible="false"`). 
It seems if you activate in server side a hidden tab, it'll add `visibilty:hidden` to the tabcontainer!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting ActiveTabIndex="0" on the TabContainer