# User control does not render in AJAX Control Toolkit TabContainer control

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

When I click the "add tab" button, server side code (`tabs.ActiveTabIndex+=1`) changes tabs, but the tab looks empty.  If I click back and forth, I could see the user control renders.  Am I missing something?

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Height="90%" Width="100%"
        ActiveTabIndex="0" OnDemand="true" AutoPostBack="false" TabStripPlacement="Top"
        CssClass="ajax__tab_xp" ScrollBars="None" UseVerticalStripPlacement="false" VerticalStripWidth="120px">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tab1" runat="server" HeaderText="1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc:UCCommSubmit ID="ucCommInfo" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="" Visible="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc:UCCommSubmit ID="UCCommSubmit1" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="" Visible="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc:UCCommSubmit ID="UCCommSubmit2" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
    <div style="padding-right: 20px; float: right">
        <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Add Tab" 
            onclick="btnNext_Click" />
    </div>


protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TabContainer1.Tabs.Count > TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex + 1)
        {
            TabContainer1.Tabs[TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex + 1].HeaderText = (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex + 1).ToString();
            TabContainer1.Tabs[TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex+1].Visible = true;
            TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex += 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is related but i had similar problems a few months ago. Here is the answer on SO which [links to forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1620618.aspx/2/10) that contains detailed informations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6307930/284240

It could also be caused by changing the `ActiveTabIndex` from codebehind without triggering the `ActiveTabChanged` event of the `TabContainer`.

Try to use this javascript function `onclick` of your button, that causes the TabContainer to trigger this event:

```
function changeActiveTab(tabContainerID,tabIndex){
    var ctrl = $find(tabContainerID);
    ctrl.set_activeTab(ctrl.get_tabs()[tabIndex]);
}
```

Then you can handle the event and change the visibility of your UserControls (and update UpdatePanels if necessary).

I just noticed that i answered [another similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5464051/284240):

<strike>Have you tried to set the ActiveTab-Property(from codebehind) or the ActiveTabIndex from codebehind or aspx?</strike>

You could also check if it works if you explicitly set the display to visible:

```
ActiveTabIndex="0" style="display:block;visibility:visible;"
```

Are you sure that the Ajax libraries are loaded correctly? Do you have other Ajax-Controls inside of your TabContainer? Check if all of your html in that page is valid.

Are you using the latest AjaxToolkit and the ToolkitScriptManager instead of the ScriptManger?

Comment: thanks Tim, very thorough steps, I appreciate it. First of all, I can't seem to be able to access tabs from the front end for some reason, the above javascript gives me undefined for set_activeTab function!! Then I've tried to set autopostback to true which seemed to have fixed the problem, then I changed scriptmanager to toolkitscript manager, then I tried to set autopostback to false I got the user control to render just fine... automagically!! :)